# final url in redirects

Tags: php, curl

I want to get final url in redirecting urls .
I have this function :

```
    function get_redirect_final_host_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
$website_host_url = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($target)['host']);
return $website_host_url;
}
```

but it doesn`t work on all links , some links are :

```
https://www.goldpoll.com/out.php?p=28017
https://investlister.com/go/lid/68/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good time ;
You need to access the curl function for those that have https
Test it:

```
function get_redirect_final_host_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // get access ssl
        curl_exec($ch);
        $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    $website_host_url = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($target)['host']);
    return $website_host_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$target = 'https://investlister.com/go/lid/68/';
$website_host_url = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($target)['host']);

echo $website_host_url; // investlister.com
```

This works exactly as you would expect

Comment: redirected url , not present url :-)